# Dynamic Programming algorithm to delete k elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was recently trying to solve a problem that took n sorted integers as input and we had to delete k integers from the array to maximize the minimum difference between two consecutive terms.

Example test case:
ARRAY: 6,7,10,13,15
delete 2 integers.

ANSWER: Integers deleted: 7,13

My approach:

Since we have to delete k integers we iterate over the array k times. In each iteration we wind the minimum difference between two consecutive terms.
Let's say that after one iteration the pair i and i+1 have minimum difference.Then we compare the difference between i-1 and i+1 and the difference between i and i+2.
If the first is larger then we delete the term i else we delete i+1.

This approach is giving me a wrong answer.

Since the constraints on n and k are low ( 1<=k<=n<=30 ).
I believe that the problem can be solved using dynamic programming but I do not know how to approach it.

Any help would be nice. I do not want the code just the algorithm and how it was derived.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this does not need DP, if you find the min and max of the sequence, remove all others, then this is the maximum difference. From your example, it you remove 7, 10, and 13, that's the maximum difference. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: The answer given to the example test case seems to be wrong. Would be better to delete 7 and 13, so that the maximum minimum difference is 4. If you delete 7 and 15, the maximum minimum distance is 3. I actually think that your algorithm is correct, but maybe you are just not handling the corner cases properly? That is, the start and end of the array.

Comment: Also I suspect that dynamic-programming may not mean what you think it means...

Comment: I would iterate through array only once, remembering k lowest differences and their position `(ix,|a[ix]-a[ix-1]|+|a[ix]-a[ix+1]|)` and deleting only after the pass. (do not take into account when you delete one item the following indexes are decremented. but also this need tweaking to avoid edge case problems...

Comment: I am sorry but the answer to the sample test case was entered incorrectly. The answer to that test case is 7 and 13. The question has been edited. Again pardon my mistake.
Also @wookie919 could you explain why you think that dynamic programming may not mean what I think it means because I do not have a firm grasp of the concepts of dynamic programming so if you suspect that I am thinking of the concept incorrectly I would like to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple cubic-time algorithm. If we decide beforehand on a minimum difference, then a linear-time greedy algorithm tells us how many elements need to be deleted (sweep once left to right, deleting only when it's necessary given past choices). Iterate through all n choose 2 = O(n^2) possible minimum differences and take the greatest that results in at most k deletions. (To get to O(n^2 log n): sort these possible minimums and use binary search.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic programming solution. Maybe a simpler solution exists, but this one is correct and definitely fast enough for given constraints:

1)Let's assume that `f(prefix_len, last_taken, deletes_count)` is the maximal difference between two consecutive numbers after processing `prefix_len` numbers in the array, deleting exactly `deletes_count` numbers and having an element with index `last_index` as the last remaining element so far.

2)`f` can be computed using the following formulas:
`f(i, i, deletes_count) = max(min(f(i - 1, j, deletes_count), abs(array[i] - array[j])))` for  `0 <= j < i`.
This formula corresponds to the case when the `i`-th element is not deleted.
`f(i, j, deletes_count) = f(i - 1, j, deletes_count - 1)`. This formula corresponds to the case when the `i`-th element is deleted.
The base case is `f(0, -1, 0) = 0`(it corresponds to an empty prefix). Maybe some other corner cases should be considered(it depends on implementation details).

3)The answer is `max(f(array.length, j, k))` for `0 <= j < array.length`.
You can find the numbers which were deleted using standard answer reconstruction techniques.

4)The time complexity is `O(m^4)`, space complexity is `O(m^3)` where `m = max(n, k)`(it is possible to get more precise upper bound using both parameters `n` and `k` but it is not necessary).

Comment: I see a few problems I'm afraid.  For a start, we're looking for the maximal *minimum* difference between consecutive remaining elements, not the maximal difference.  So I think it's better for f(prefix_len, last_taken, deletes_count) to store the minimum consecutive difference.  Also, except for at the top level, we're only ever interested in solved subproblems for prefixes in which the last element was not deleted, so one parameter goes away. ...

Comment: ... So I would say, instead, let g(prefix_len, deletes_count) be the maximal minimum difference between consecutive remaining elements on the first prefix_len elements *that does not involve deleting the final (prefix_len-th) element*, and then we get g(i, deletes_count) = max(min(g(j, deletes_count - (i - j - 1)), abs(array[i] - array[j]))), with the max taken over all 0 <= j < i.  Notice that this way we also take into account how forcing a gap between i and j reduces the number of deletes available to the subproblem by (i - j - 1).

Comment: This doesn't yet handle the possibility of deleting the rightmost element at the top level -- though interestingly, if we're only interested in one solution (i.e. not enumerating all of them) this doesn't matter, since any optimal solution that does delete the rightmost element can be converted to a solution that is at least as good (i.e. still optimal) by deleting the first non-deleted element to its left instead.  (Think about which sets of consecutive pairs each of the two deletions removes.) ...

Comment: ... But in any case, deleting the last 1 <= i <= k elements is equivalent to g(len(array) - i, k - i), so if you wanted to enumerate all optimal solutions, you could also test whether each of these k subproblem solutions has optimal score, and if so, backtrack through them as well as the main solution, g(len(array), k).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, my formula was incorrect. Thanks for pointing this out. I have fixed it. I know that it is possible to get rid of one the parameters, I just decided to keep my solution as intuitive as possible because n and k are very small.